# What is the equivalent of "touch" on windows cmd?

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, command

I'm trying to create a JavaScript `.js` file via the PowerShell Command-line, however, when I tried echo the file just disappears right after I create it. Is there an equal to the BASH command `$ touch` in PowerShell?

[Echo Attempt in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

[image: E7NBB.png]

Comment: This is not a programming related question, but rather a general software question. It should probably be asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Jesse don't be so rough on Joyce. You are correct, but she's new, and its not totally off subject. I have seen people ask worst.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your in PowerShell, which is slightly different than the Windows CMD-Prompt.

---

## PowerShell Equivalent to the Linux Command `$> touch`

---

In ***PowerShell*** they the *Command*, a ***Cmdlet***, and unlike **BASH** there is a specific *Cmdlet* for creating new files & directories (among other entities as well).

---

### The PowerShell Cmdlet: `$> New-Item`

---

###### You can (for the most part) replace the **BASH `$> touch` command** with the ***PowerShell CmdLet*** `$> New-item` when creating files in a shell-environment.

Creating new items works a bit differently in **PowerShell&** than in Linux Shells (I am specifically referring to Bash in this answer).
For example, Windows PowerShell's CmdLet `$> New-item` can create more than one type of item — *for example, PowerShell create both directories, and files* — therefore; in PowerShell, you need to specify the item type. To specify an item-type you will use the ItemType flag `-ItemType <argument>`. The pseudo-argument  was a place holder I added in. Actual `-ItemType` arguments would be `File` &/or `Directory`.

### EXAMPLE | New File:

---

###### Here is the Cmdlet format thats considered the standard for creating new files:

```
    New-Item -Path 'A:\testing\one\two\three.txt' -ItemType File
```

Creates the file, ***`three.txt`*** in the directory  ***`two`***, and the file's full pathname would be, ***`A:\testing\one\two\three.txt`***

### EXAMPLE | New Directory:

---

###### The **`$> New-item`** CmdLet is specific for creating files & directories. This is somewhat unique, as the Linux Shell **BASH** implements the `$> mkdir` command, but it only makes directories, not files. BASH demonstrates that a SHELL doesn't have to have a command thats specificly for file creation, however; that's not to say that having a file-creation command doesn't have any benifits. But, in Windows, you can, and you should, use the `New-Item` CmdLet for creating directories.

###### Here is how to create a directory when using PowerShell:

```
New-Item -Path 'Z:\sum-directory' -ItemType Directory
```

This command creates a new directory named ***`sum-directory`***. The directory is located in the drive-letter  **`Z:\`**, and the directory's full pathname would be  ***`Z:\sum-directory`***

---

###### FOR MORE INFORMATION ABOUT THIS TOPIC, PLEASE VISIT:

---

###### *[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-files-and-folders?view=powershell-7.1#creating-files-and-folders](http://%20######%20For%20more%20information%20on%20this%20topic,%20please%20visit:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-files-and-folders?view=powershell-7.1#creating-files-and-folders)*

---

Comment: thank you (it's powershell i miswrote the words sorry)

Answer (score 6):

You should use `type` or `copy` instead of `echo`.

> C:> type nul >> "file.txt"

or

> C:> copy nul "file.txt"

This link has more information:
https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-touch-command-equivalent/

Comment: q= (-_- ) The Windows bugs are fixed: "`type nul >> ...`" did nothing, and "`copy nul ...`" did overwrite file with empty-file (tested on Windows 7).

Comment: the above answer's link is useful, but the above is a correct answer for Windows CMD, which is apparently different from Windows PowerShell! (the op was confusing).

For Powershell the correct answer is `PS C:\> New-Item "file.txt"` or, even shorter than the Unix command:  `PS C:\> ni file.txt`.